# What's the JSF implementation version that JBoss 7.1.1.Final has?

Tags: java, jsf, jboss

What's the JSF implementation version that JBoss 7.1.1.Final has? and how can I know, and also how can I upgrade it.

I just know that it's mojarra implementation, but nothing more.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final is shipped with JSF 2.1.7. See the release notes [here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/AS711FinalReleaseNotes)

You can update the JSF modules like this:

The jboss-jsf-api jar is located at

```
${jboss.home.dir}/modules/javax/faces/api/main
```

Download the latest 2.0.3.Final from [here](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/jboss/spec/javax/faces/jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec/) and place it in the above folder and edit the module.xml to this:

```
<resource-root path="jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.3.Final.jar"/>
```

The jsf-impl jar is located at

```
${jboss.home.dir}/modules/com/sun/jsf-impl/main
```

Download jsf-impl 2.1.10 from [here](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/com/sun/faces/jsf-impl/2.1.10-jbossorg-1/) and place it in the above folder and edit the module.xml to this:

```
<resource-root path="jsf-impl-2.1.10-jbossorg-1.jar"/>
```

Now we have the JSF libraries updated to the versions available in 7.1.3.Final-SNAPSHOT.