# What is the Jboss X JSF implementation version matrix?

Tags: jsf, jboss

For the code evolution purposes of a legade system, I'd like to know which Jboss version was the first to support JSF 2.x ?

Comment: Each version has releasenotes, easy to find via Google.

Comment: Looks like it started with JBoss 7.X [whats the jsf implementation version that jboss 7.1.1 final has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493884/whats-the-jsf-implementation-version-that-jboss-7-1-1-final-has) wildfly 8 0nly had 1.2, wildfly 9 and higher has 2.x

Answer (score 0):

I found at:
https://access.redhat.com/articles/112673#EAP_6

I think that can be useful for planning new releases.